# How to get this data in JSON in android

Tags: android, json

I have this data form this URL 

http://api.clicky.com/api/stats/4?site_id=32020&sitekey=71bf7c1681e22468&type=visitors&output=json&json_callback=data%22 

and how to get this in android, 
my problem is how to access all this objects and array, help me

```
[
  {
    "type": "visitors",
    "dates": [
      {
        "date": "2014-12-25",
        "items": [
          { "value":"70" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: To access this data you have to made an async call to the given api link. Then in response you will get this json data. Through that response you can get your meaningful data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("here is your json string ") ;
    int count = jsonArray.length() ;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i) ;
        String type = jsonObject.optString("type") ;
        JSONArray datesArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("dates") ;
        int datesCount = datesArray.length() ;
        for(int j = 0; j< datesCount; j++){
           JSONObject dateItem = datesArray.get(j) ;
           String dateStr = dateItem.optString("date");
           JSONArray itemsArray = dateItem.optJSONArray("items");
           for(int f = 0 ; f < itemsArray.length(); f++){
               JSONObject valueJson = itemsArray.get(f);
               String value = valueJson.optString("value");
           }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should try to understand it~

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("here is your json string ") ; for String means result that we pass right

Comment: i got it now thanks for the help but there are some uncompleted methods are there ok

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use GSON library for parsing your JSON. Just create class for JSON and use this code:

```
new Gson().fromJson(json, MyGsonClass.class);
```